# Reading repetitive sub-sections of a CSV line / record?

Tags: csv, csvhelper

In CSVHelper, is it possible to read repetetive sub-records from a single line of the source CSV file?

The CSV format I am working with has sections like the following:

(*All this text would be a* single line *of the CSV file*)

```
TYPICAL/EXTREME PERIODS,6,
Summer - Week Nearest Max Temperature For Period,Extreme,7/13,7/19,
Summer - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,6/22,6/28,
Winter - Week Nearest Min Temperature For Period,
Extreme,1/20,1/26,Winter - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,12/ 8,12/14,
Autumn - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,10/ 6,10/12,
Spring - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,4/26,5/ 2
```

The first field `TYPICAL...` is just a constant marker.

The second field `6` indicates how many repeating sub-records there will be.

Thus the following 6 blocks of fields each have the same format, 4 fields each. I would like to read / map each of these 6 sections to an individual class object, each of the same type.

---

I can see in the [documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading) that there are many ways to parse the data, but none quite seem to map to this. It is possible to read all the fields on a given line / record as an enumerable list of values (or a dynamically sized `dynamic` object) but these approaches lose most of the benefit of CSVHelper, namely that it can map the data to an object for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a good way to use all the mapping features of CsvHelper for your example, but it would be fairly easy to build the objects manually.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("TYPICAL/EXTREME PERIODS,6,Summer - Week Nearest Max Temperature For Period,Extreme,7/13,7/19,Summer - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,6/22,6/28,Winter - Week Nearest Min Temperature For Period,Extreme,1/20,1/26,Winter - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,12/ 8,12/14,Autumn - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,10/ 6,10/12,Spring - Week Nearest Average Temperature For Period,Typical,4/26,5/ 2");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

            csv.Read();

            List<Foo> result = new List<Foo>();
            var rows = csv.GetField<int>(1);
            var index = 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                var foo = new Foo
                {
                    Description = csv.GetField<string>(index),
                    Type = csv.GetField<string>(index + 1),
                    Start = csv.GetField<string>(index + 2),
                    End = csv.GetField<string>(index + 3)
                };

                result.Add(foo);
                index += 4;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this is very close to what I ended up doing. I could not find any way to really use its class mapping either, but in the end this approach worked very well.